# How do I create an p2pkh raw transaction using the latest Bitcoin core version? Any help? Thanks

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, raw-transaction, p2pkh, createrawtransaction

Like the title says I need of help here, how can I create an p2pkh raw transaction using the latest version of Bitcoin core is it even possible? What are the required fields do I need to use the version #? How do I write the inputs and outputs out in what format?